# Nonlinear root finding

Tags: python, numerical-methods, root-finding

I need a stable nonlinear root finding for a function that takes two inputs and return two nonlinear output in Python without "Black Box" libraries

I found that the Newton-Raphson algorithm is helpful but it doesn't converge always, Then I read about BFGS but I didn't know how to write this algorithm with two inputs - two output functions, just like I did in Newton Raphson

```
def root_finding(f, x0, y0, eps=1e-6, max_iter=100):

    """
    Finds the root of a two-input, two-output function using the Newton-Raphson method.
    
    Parameters:
    f (callable): the function to find the root of; should take two inputs and return a two-element array
    x0 (float): initial guess for the first input
    y0 (float): initial guess for the second input
    eps (float, optional): convergence tolerance; iterations stop when the norm of the increment is less than eps
    max_iter (int, optional): maximum number of iterations
    
    Returns:
    tuple: the root (x, y) 
    """
    x = x0
    y = y0
    for i in range(1):
        # Compute the function and its Jacobian at the current guess
        fxy = np.array(f(x, y))
        print(fxy)
        J = np.array([
            [f(x + eps, y)[0] - fxy[0], f(x, y + eps)[0] - fxy[0]],
            [f(x + eps, y)[1] - fxy[1], f(x, y + eps)[1] - fxy[1]]
        ]) / eps
        print(J)
        
        # Compute the increment and update the guess
        if np.linalg.det(J)==0:
            print('The Matrix is singular')
            return None,None
        
        delta = np.linalg.solve(J, -fxy)
        x += delta[0]
        y += delta[1]
        
        # Check for convergence
        if np.linalg.norm(delta) < eps:
            return x, y
    
    print( RuntimeError("Failed to converge after {} iterations".format(max_iter)))
    return None,None
```

Comment: I'm not sure why there have been "close" votes, but maybe you can prevent closing by a) pasting the BFGS algo for 1-input-1-output functions, b) asking a clear question, like "how do I transform this for 2-input-2-output functions?" (maybe explaining why it's different from how you did it for Newton-Raphson)

Comment: I don't understand, though: Newton-Raphson is an algorithm for finding the roots of a function, while BFGS (Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno) is an algorithm for finding the minima of a function, which is quite a different thing. How could you adapt it to finding roots?

Comment: Indeed, the quasi-Newton method that generalizes the secant method is the (adjoint) Broyden method. The question has no answer, such a panacea does not exist. There are algorithms that work reasonably well for specific classes of equations and systems, but not the one method to rule them all.

Comment: There are things you can do with the Newton method to make it more robust, such as limiting the step size to either a maximal relative change, or for the variables to stay within an a priori known domain. You can also solve it as an optimisation problem by minimising the sum of square residuals of the equations. In some cases, this can help robustness as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.